# qnamaker location - europe

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

Does anyone know whether it's possible to publish the QnAMaker in Europe? I can only publish it in the West US which results in quite a bit of latency when calling the service from our backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on Cognitive Services API Management located [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services?page=2), there is no endpoint for Europe (in comparison to LUIS where there are several locations):
[image]

So no, sorry.

Comment: Working with QnaMaker for 2 years now and indeed, the latency sucks. Luckely its successor (language service) can be published to Western Europe.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the latency, you could decide to migrate to Azure Cognitive Service for Language which can be published in Western and  Northern Europe.If  you are using Bot Framework SDK to talk to this service, bear in mind that it is not yet ready for the new Language Service.